# Google maps javascript v3 infoWindow in front of another

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have two infoWindows for two markers: infoWindow1 for marker1 and infoWindow2 for marker2. When I click on marker1 the infoWindow1 is shown. When I click on marker2 the infoWindow2 is shown in front of infoWindow1. But I want infoWindow1 keeps always in front. How can I do that?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info windows take a zIndex parameter. Did you try that?

All InfoWindows are displayed on the map in order of their zIndex, with higher values displaying in front of InfoWindows with lower values. By default, InfoWindows are displayed according to their latitude, with InfoWindows of lower latitudes appearing in front of InfoWindows at higher latitudes. InfoWindows are always displayed in front of markers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved the problem yet. Using the zIndex property for the infoWindows.